# How to enable checkbox when associated textview is clicked

Tags: android

I'm using a CheckBox and TextView in my App(I;m using a image view between Checkbox and Textview, so I couldn't use the CheckBox Text). I want to enable/disable my Checkbox if the corresponding TextView is clicked. Anyone please help me.

Comment: You mean, you want your checkbox to be _checked/unchecked_ when the whole (supposed) LinearLayout is clicked? -- Please provide some code, anyway.

Comment: You can set Visibility of checkbox.When user clicks on textview set the visibility of checkbox to true.I think you want this.

Answer (score 3):

Just try this:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="First text box"
     android:id="@+id/tb_1"
     />
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cb_1"
        />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second text box"
        android:id="@+id/tb_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cb_2"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements  View.OnClickListener {

private TextView tv1;
private CheckBox cb1;
private TextView tv2;
private CheckBox cb2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tb_1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tb_2);

    cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_2);

    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId())
   {
       case (R.id.tb_1):
       {
           cb1.setChecked(!cb1.isChecked());
           break;
       }
       case (R.id.tb_2):
       {
           cb2.setChecked(!cb2.isChecked());
           break;
       }
   }
}
}
```

When you click on one of `TextView` you just set current value `setChecked` for nested `CheckBox` (for one or many). And that is all what you need.
Hope it's help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its an easy one. Implement a click listener on your textview and check and uncheck your checkbox in the onClickListener ..